# Spread out field lines and divergence

Tags: vector-analysis

It can be shown by calculation of divergence of a field like $(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}})$ that it's divergence is positive. But I can't understand the geometrical essence of this statement.

It doesn't seem that inward flow is less than outward (as the speed is the same). I know it can be interpreted like tendency to escape neighborhood of a point spreading out in different directions.

Can you please explain me what spreading out has in common with flow through a infinitesimal sphere around the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field of constant length *and direction* certainly represents "incompressible" flow, but constant length alone does not, roughly because the values of the field may be "spreading out" at each point (as they are for your field $F$), or "squeezing together" at each point (as they are for the field $-F$, which also has constant length). It may help to think of a crowd of people, each walking at the same constant speed, but either leaving or entering a stadium. The density of people per unit area may well change.

There are at least two of ways to get at your question with calculus: one using Gauss's theorem, and one using the definition of a flow.

1. Let $F = (F_{1}, F_{2})$ be a smooth vector field in the plane, $D$ a small disk centered at a point $(a_{1}, a_{2})$, $S = \partial D$ the boundary circle, and $\mathbf{n}$ the outward unit normal field along $S$. If $dA$ denotes the area element in the plane and $ds$ denotes the arc length element along $S$, Gauss's theorem asserts that
   $$
   \iint_{D} \operatorname{div}(F)\, dA = \int_{\partial D} (F \cdot \mathbf{n})\, ds.
   $$
   Since $F$ is smooth, the left-hand side is approximately equal to
   $$
   \operatorname{div}(F)(a_{1}, a_{2}) \cdot \operatorname{Area}(D),
   $$
   while the right-hand side is the net flux of $F$ across $S = \partial D$. In the limit as $\operatorname{Area}(D) \to 0$, the net flux across $S$ per unit area enclosed is the divergence of $F$ at the center of $D$.
2. With notation as above, and working locally in space and time, there exists a *flow map* $\Phi:D \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to \mathbf{R}^{2}$ satisfying
   $$
   \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(x_{1}, x_{2}, t) = F(x_{1}, x_{2}),\quad
   \Phi(x_{1}, x_{2}, 0) = (x_{1}, x_{2}).
   $$
   The flow map can be expanded as a series in $t$:
   $$
   \Phi(x_{1}, x_{2}, t)
     = \left[\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
         x_{1} + t F_{1}(x_{1}, x_{2}) + O(t^{2}) \\
         x_{2} + t F_{2}(x_{1}, x_{2}) + O(t^{2}) \\
       \end{array}\right].
   $$
   The infinitesimal spatial behavior of the flow map is given by the spatial differential
   $$
   D\Phi(x_{1}, x_{2}, t)
     = \left[\begin{array}{@{}rr@{}}
         1 + t \dfrac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{1}, x_{2}) + O(t^{2}) &
             t \dfrac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}(x_{1}, x_{2}) + O(t^{2}) \\
             t \dfrac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{1}, x_{2}) + O(t^{2}) &
         1 + t \dfrac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}(x_{1}, x_{2}) + O(t^{2}) \\
       \end{array}\right].
   $$
   Particularly, the area of the image of $D$ under the time $t$ flow is approximately the area of $D$ multiplied by
   $$
   \det\bigl(D\Phi(a_{1}, a_{2}, t)\bigr)
     = 1 + t \operatorname{div}(F)(a_{1}, a_{2}) + O(t^{2}).
   $$
   Again, $\operatorname{div}(F)$ measures the infinitesimal (in space) rate of change of area with respect to time under the flow of $F$.

(Both explanations generalize with obvious modifications to vector fields on $\mathbf{R}^{n}$. The second can be modified to show that the curl of $F$ measures the axis and angular speed of the flow of a vector field on $\mathbf{R}^{3}$.)

Comment: Yeah, sure, being interpreted as a speed of area change makes it clear. Thank you!